# Why does SetBkMode not want to work on another PC?

Tags: winapi

I have a c++ application that outputs text using SetBkMode:

```
    wndDC=GetDC(wnd->getWnd());// hdc основного окна
    watermark=CreateCompatibleDC(wndDC);// hdc текста
    HBITMAP RAWwatermarkHbm=CreateCompatibleBitmap(wndDC,watermarkRectRAW.right,watermarkRectRAW.bottom);// HBITMAP для сырого текста
    SelectObject(watermark,RAWwatermarkHbm);
    SetBkMode(watermark,TRANSPARENT);
    SetTextColor(watermark,RGB(150,150,150));
    DrawText (watermark,watermarkText,-1,&textRect,DT_LEFT);
```

...

```
AlphaBlend(wndDC,watermarkRect.left,watermarkRect.top,watermarkRect.right,watermarkRect.bottom,
               watermark,watermarkRectRAW.left,watermarkRectRAW.top,watermarkRectRAW.right,watermarkRectRAW.bottom,
               this->bf);
```

wndDC and watermark are public fields of the class.
the text is first drawn in hdc watermark, and then in the hdc of the main window using AlphaBlend. Everything works fine on my PC, but if I run it on a laptop, the background turns black[image]

[image]

I collect on mingw under windows

Comment: "*if I run it on a laptop, the background turns black*"" - the screenshots you provided don't show that.  Also, on a side note, you don't show how you are creating `watermark`, but when using `SelectObject()` you need to save the old `HBITMAP` and restore it before freeing `watermark`.

Comment: Sounds like you're relying on GDI to clear the alpha channel of the area around the text, but I'm not sure GDI is reliable in that respect since it has no knowledge of alpha. You may be better off using Gdiplus. Weird behavior like this could also be due to a resource leak as suggested by Remy.

Comment: Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?